# Repeating function at the end of function

Tags: jquery

I have created a function which toggles the classes of elements in my HTML with a set time out function. I would like to repeat this function at the end, quite like a loop. I have tried calling the function at the end of this function inside itself, this does not work. What is the proper way to do this?

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    var rectanglePre = jQuery('.rectangle-pre');
    function myRemovePre(index){
         jQuery(rectanglePre[index]).toggleClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }
    function transparent(index){
         jQuery(rectanglePre[index]).toggleClass('rectangle-transparent');
    }
    function preloader(index){
        setTimeout(function(){ myRemovePre(1) }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){ myRemovePre(0) }, 200);
        setTimeout(function(){ transparent(0) }, 300);
        setTimeout(function(){ transparent(1) }, 400);
    }   
    preloader(0);
});
```

Comment: Have a look at `setInterval()` to time a function periodically

Comment: Why doesn't `preloader()` use its `index` parameter?

Comment: thanks, this works however it leaves a pause at the beginning.

Comment: @Jack may be a function call as you have now, followed by a `setInterval` to avoid pause at beginning

Comment: @Lapskaus, this works but I have to repeat the function before the setInterval, is there a way to use this without rewriting code outside of this?

Comment: #1 and easiest, like you do, call the function, then set the interval, to have the first call immediately. #2 Method, use an immediatly invoking function inside the setInterval() [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should call itself after the last action in the `setTimeout()`.

```
    function preloader(index){
        setTimeout(function(){ myRemovePre(1) }, 100);
        setTimeout(function(){ myRemovePre(0) }, 200);
        setTimeout(function(){ transparent(0) }, 300);
        setTimeout(function(){ transparent(1); preloader(index) }, 400);
    }
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var rectanglePre = jQuery('.rectangle-pre');

  function myRemovePre(index) {
    jQuery(rectanglePre[index]).toggleClass('rectangle-transparent');
  }

  function transparent(index) {
    jQuery(rectanglePre[index]).toggleClass('rectangle-transparent');
  }

  function preloader(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      myRemovePre(1)
    }, 100);
    setTimeout(function() {
      myRemovePre(0)
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function() {
      transparent(0)
    }, 300);
    setTimeout(function() {
      transparent(1);
      preloader(index);
    }, 400);
  }
  preloader(0);
});
```

```css
.rectangle-pre {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.rectangle-pre.rectangle-transparent {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rectangle-pre"></div>
<p>
<div class="rectangle-pre"></div>
```